# How to grant a service principal access to data object with Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

On this page it makes it clear how to grant access to a data object for a user or a role.
https://docs.databricks.com/data-governance/table-acls/object-privileges.html

I want to do it for a service principal (a service principal on workspace level).
I can't find info regarding how to reference the service principal.

Can it be done? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have added the service principal account to your workspace,
you can use the UUID(ApplicationID) of the service principal in order to grant access:

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA alpha TO `UUID`;
```

Comment: Yes, I found this out after some test myself as well. Still think this should be better documented from databricks side.